# Replace NaN values with interpolation of they near values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have this data

```
Mat=[1 2 3 5;6 14 -9999 4;10 11 12 13;14 -9999 16 17;18 19 -9999 -9999]
Mat(Mat<0)=NaN

Mat =
1     2     3     5
6     14   NaN     9
10    11    12    13
14   NaN    16    17
18    19   NaN   NaN
```

I want to replace the NaN with the mean of the right and left value. I try to convert the all matrix in vector but the location of de NaN is importat so do this

```
Row = Mat(2,:)
Row = inpaint_nans(Row)
```

But error show

```
Undefined function 'inpaint_nans' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

The result must be like this

```
Mat =
1     2     3     5
6     14    9     4
10    11    12    13
14    15    16    17
18    19   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Your original `Mat(2,3)` value seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[r,c]=find(isnan(Mat(:,2:end-1)));      % Finding indexes of NaN excluding the edges/corners
c=c+1; % To counter that we started from second column
for iter=1:length(c)
    Mat(r(iter),c(iter))= mean([Mat(r(iter),c(iter)-1)  Mat(r(iter),c(iter)+1)]);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with no loops:

```
Mat = [1 2 3 5;6 14 nan 4;10 11 12 13;14 nan 16 17;18 19 nan nan];
% get the transposed location of all NaNs:
loc = reshape(1:numel(Mat),size(Mat.')).'.*isnan(Mat);
% remove first and last column:
nan_loc = nonzeros(loc(:,2:end-1));
% replace them by the mean of the values to thier sides:
tMat = Mat.';
tMat(nan_loc) = mean([tMat(nan_loc-1) tMat(nan_loc+1)],2);
Mat = tMat.'
```

Result:

```
Mat =
     1     2     3     5
     6    14     9     4
    10    11    12    13
    14    15    16    17
    18    19   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: this is buggy. e.g;   if `Mat(1,1) =-9999`, Another example: if `Mat(3,4) =-9999`

Comment: Corrected! though I'm still not sure what the OP wants to do with the values in the corners.

Comment: I put the values in the corners to represent NaN that can be replace by the mean of the near values.

Comment: @AnesG Well my answer does exactly what you accepted as an answer, and for a 1000*1000 matrix it takes less than **4%** of the time of using a loop (**<4ms** in compare to **>1 sec**).

Answer (score 1):

If you have R2016a or later you can do:

```
% Compute moving mean, omitting the NaNs
MatMean = movmean(Mat, 3, 2, 'omitnan');
InterpMat = Mat;
% Set NaN values to the average
InterpMat(isnan(Mat)) = MatMean(isnan(Mat));
```

The only hiccup here is that it doesn't preserve the `NaN`s in locations where you don't have 2 values to average (that is, it doesn't take the average of `19` and `NaN` to be `NaN`, but rather `19`).  You can get around this with a post-processing step:

```
% Find regions where either neighbor of a NaN is NaN
N = size(Mat, 1);
mask = (movsum(isnan(Mat), [1 0], 2) == 2) | (movsum(isnan(Mat), [0 1], 2) == 2);
% Reset those points to NaN
InterpMat(mask) = NaN;
```

Comment: Well it's less extensible, but then I suppose you could do:
`N = size(Mat, 1);
MeanMat = 0.5*([false(N, 1), Mat(:, 1:(end-1))] + [Mat(:, 2:end), false(N, 1)]); 
InterpMat = Mat;
InterpMat(isnan(Mat)) = MeanMat(isnan(Mat))`